# Iterated Elimination of Stricly Dominated Strategies

Tags: game-theory

Which actions remain after iterated elimination of strictly dominated actions?
Is there a dominant strategy for either player? If yes, name it, if not, explain why.

```
               player 2

            [C]       [NC]
      [P]  (2,10)    (-2,0)
```

player 1

```
      [NP](-10,-5)    (0,0)
```

In my opinion, all survive the iterated elimination of strictly dominated strategies... For example, for player 2, NC is favorable if and only if player 1 plays NP. However, Player 1 won't play NP, because he won't risk to get -10 utility... So he would prefer to play P; in this case Player 2 would like to play C, instead of NC. It's very confusing for me... Am I right? If I am wrong, please tell me what's the right answer.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, neither player has a strictly dominates strategy, hence neither player has a dominant strategy.